# Add Weekday as locale’s full name to my programs welcome message

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, string-formatting

So for a bit of fun I want to add Hello! Happy "Monday"(for example) when my program opens up in Terminal.

I have been using the strftime directives for naming my folders that get generated. But I am a little bit stuck how to add this to my opening message within in the print function.

This is what I have so far -

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import datetime

try: #Handle Python 2.7
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
pass

#Change Directory Paths to Project Drives 
subfolders = ("ari", "sound", "md5" , "mxf" , "h264" , "reports" , "ale")
parent_format = "{0:03d}_{1:%y%m%d}_Unit_Project"
path = ('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/thenightfactory/Documents')
path2 = ('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/thenightfactory/Pictures')
os.chdir(path)

 #Below is where I want to have the day come up 
print ("")
print("Hello! Please Select A Shooting Day To Create Today's Folders:")
print ('\033[91m' + "This will only work until midnight and can only be three integers eg. 023" + '\033[0m')
print("=" * 80)
```

I apologise if this is really obvious - I'm kind of just learning as I go and trying to fix problems as they arise.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Use the `"%A"` flag from [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting today's weekday:

```
from datetime import datetime

weekday = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%A")
print("Hello, happy " + weekday + "!")
```

Comment: So then adding it to my print line should I just have to write 

print ("hello! Happy "%A" blah blah ") ? But obviously that doesn't work. So how am I able to add day within that text if that makes any sense ?

Comment: Not exactly. But I changed my answered and hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: ahh okay I see what you mean. That's solved it, really appreciate the help!